# Function for store data - C++

Tags: c++, file

Given the following definition for a **NODE** in a linked list:

```
struct NODE {
int data;
NODE* next;
};
```

I want a function to store the nodes with odd data to a given file (each line should contain a single integer number) [use c++ classes from ]

I wrote this code but there is some problems with the output .. Where is the wrong or what is the best solution for the question??

```
void storeOddElements(NODE *head, char *FileName)
{
    NODE *p = head;
    int count = 0;

    ofstream fp(FileName, ios::out);
    if(!fp.is_open()) return;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if ((p->data % 2) == 1)
            count++;
        p = p->next;

    }

    int odd_store[count], i=0;
    while (p !=NULL) {
        if ((p->data % 2) == 0)
            p = p->next;
        else
        {
            odd_store[i] = p->data;
            p = p->next;
            i++;
        }
    }

    int temp;
    for (int z = 0; z <= i-1; z++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (odd_store[z] <= odd_store[j]) {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = odd_store[z];
                odd_store[z] = odd_store [j];
                odd_store[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
        fp << odd_store[x] << endl;
    }
    fp.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. If your code is not working correctly (as you mentioned, your output has problems), it is off-topic for this site. You might try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you can word the question in a way that fits the criteria on that page. Once your code works correctly, you're welcome to ask a new question here and we can review it for improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing a file name?

```
void storeOddElements(NODE *head, char *FileName)
```

A file stream is the same concept as a stream. So writ the code to use a stream. Then you can pass `std::cout` while you are testing then swap in `std::ofstream` object when you are ready to pass a file.

Technically this is illegal C++;

```
int odd_store[count];
```

To be legal `count` must be determined at compile time. Though some compilers support this as an extension. It is better to use `std::vector<>` for this situation.

**BUT** why are you counting and storing the output values into an array in the first place? That seems like a redundant waste of time. Just print them directly to the file stream.

Then you sort the stored values. I see no requirement that the data be sorted.

Looking at your sort you implement a swap operation rather than using `std::swap()`. But you don't even need to implement a sort function there is a standard one `std::sort` that implements a better algorithm than the `bubble sort` you are using.

Bu the easiest way is to store them in a sorted container when you retrieve them from the list `std::set` would work for that.

Lastly the copy from the container to the output uses a loop. Learn how to use the standard algorithm or the range based for to make the code easier to read.

Also prefer to use `"\n"` rather than `std::endl`. Using `std::endl` will only slow your code down.

Personally I would write it like this:

```
void storeOddElements(NODE *head, std::ostream& output)
{
    std::copy_if(NodeIterator(head), NodeIterator(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(output, "\n"),
                 [](auto const& val){return val % 2 == 1;});
}
```

Now you only need to define a `NodeIterator` that can iterate over a list of `Node`. :-)

OK Got bored. Here is a `NodeIterator`.

```
class NodeIterator
{
    Node* current;
    public:
        NodeIterator(Node* begin = nullptr)
            : current(begin)
        {}
        NodeIterator& operator++()   {current = current->next;return *this}
        NodeIterator  operator++(int){NodeIterator result(*this); (*this)++; return result;}

        bool operator==(NodeIterator const& other) const {return current == other.current;}
        bool operator!=(NodeIterator const& other) const {return !(*this == other);}
        int operator*()                       {return current->data;}

        // iterator traits
        using difference_type   = long;
        using value_type        = int;
        using pointer           = int*;
        using reference         = int&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
};
```

If we need to sort the data before output then we can use:

```
void storeOddElements(Node *head, std::ostream& output)
{
    std::set<int>  sortedData;
    std::copy_if(NodeIterator(head), NodeIterator(),
                 std::inserter(sortedData, sortedData.end()),
                 [](auto const& val){return val % 2 == 1;});

    std::copy(std::begin(sortedData), std::end(sortedData),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(output, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. https://b.top4top.net/p_659l5g2b1.png .. can you help me what should I do .. there is some errrors

Comment: Fixed all the slopyness in my code. Though I use `Node` rather than `NODE` as identifiers in all uppercase are traditionally reserved for macros (and thus not safe to use).